# Элементы коллекции Set в порядке добавления

Tags: java, коллекции

Здравствуйте. Есть Set, но элементы его расположены не в порядке добавления. Почему и как с этим бороться? Как сделать чтобы элементы сета располагались в порядке добавления? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Разобрался. Нужно использовать LinkedHashSet